# Can I Get User ID at Login?

Tags: login, id

My goal is to allow my users to select their choice of redirect page after login but it doesn't seem that the user ID is available after login?

Here is my code.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!!

```php
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    
    $myID = get_current_user_id();
    if ($myID > 0) {
        $my_redirect = xprofile_get_field_data( "Home Page" ,  $myID ); 
        switch($my_redirect) {
            case 'Community':
                return bp_loggedin_user_domain();   
                die;
            case 'Announcements':
                return home_url('/announcements');  
                die;
            case 'Prayers':
                return home_url('/prayers');    
                die;
            case 'Watch':
                return home_url('/watch');  
                die;                
        }
    }
    return home_url();  
    die;
}
 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/),

> The `$current_user` global may not be available at the time this filter is run. So you should use the `$user` global or the `$user` parameter passed to this filter.

```php
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
  // Don't modify the redirect on error.
  if( wp_is_error( $user ) )
    return $redirect_to;

  $myID = $user->ID;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Though, it looks like `get_current_user_id()` actually uses the `$user` global - this may not be the solution.